Unhandled database error not showing error page
I have a .NET 8 web application that uses the data protection feature where a SQL database table is used for the keyring values.
If the database connection fails, the application is unable to obtain the keyring. Instead of seeing the error page, I get a 500 error.
In Program.cs, I have this code:
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

// ... more code here

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = Constants.SessionName;
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); 

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

// Exception occurs here.
app.Run();

In Error.cshtml, I have this markup:
@page
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">@Model.ExceptionMessage</h2>

<h3>The administrator at Company Name has been notified.</h3>

In Error.cshtml.cs, I have this code:
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public string? RequestId { get; set; }
    public string? ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

    private readonly ILogger<ErrorModel> _logger;

    public ErrorModel(ILogger<ErrorModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        ExceptionMessage = "An error occurred while processing your request.";
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;

        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
        HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error?.Source == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection")
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "An error occurred accessing the database.";
        }
    }
}

To simulate the error, I stopped the SQL Server Express service. But the exception also occurs when an Azure SQL database connection times out and retries are exceeded.
The exception that is thrown is

CryptographicException: an error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data

It has something to do with the AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext> logic. Of course, if I remove that logic, it doesn't crash.
How do I handle this race condition where the data protection keyring cannot be obtained, and the error handler doesn't intercept the error? I simply want to show the error page.
I was expecting the error page to show the error message.
I tried to put a try/catch block around the last line in Program.cs, but it didn't catch the exception.
try
{
    app.Run();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Do something here.
    // I don't know what to do here anyway. 
}

I tried to write a custom exception handler according to the document below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0

public class CustomExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<CustomExceptionHandler> logger;

    public CustomExceptionHandler(ILogger<CustomExceptionHandler> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = exception.Message;

        logger.LogError(
            "Error Message: {exceptionMessage}, Time of occurrence {time}",
            exceptionMessage, DateTime.UtcNow);

        if (exception?.Source == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection")
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            //httpContext.Response.Redirect("Index"); // tried Error here too.
            httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Database error. Please refresh the page or try again later.";
            return ValueTask.FromResult(true);
        }

        // Return false to continue with the default behavior
        // - or - return true to signal that this exception is handled
        return ValueTask.FromResult(false);
    }
}

I set a breakpoint inside TryHandleAsync, and I step through the logic. It returns true, but I get too many redirects, if I redirect. I can write an error message, but it's not a very attractive.
What should I do in the custom error handler?

May I know if you have a chance to check the solution below? If you need further help, please let me know, have a nice day.

You can create a custom middleware to capture all the errors you want. The most important  thing is we need tp register it in the top like below.

namespace WebApplication6
{
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    public class CustomExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<CustomExceptionMiddleware> _logger;

        public CustomExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<CustomExceptionMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Source == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection")
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred with Data Protection.");
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                }
                else if (ex.Source == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred with DB Connection.");
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                }
                else {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred with other reason.");
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Here is the test result
I use a wrong db connection string, and please check the test result.


